# F1.0 and beyond

Tags: fast-lenses

can you suggest me lenses as fast as or faster then f1.0, which I can use on a modern Nikon FX DSLR (D600)? It is for artistic purposes, so sharpness, autofocus etc. do not count here.

Thank you.

Comment: Prima facie, this is asking for product recommendations and therefore off-topic here. However, as you're almost certainly going to be looking at the second hand market, it's not going to have the usual problem of being redundant in two years, so I'm not voting to close this one.

Comment: No problem, but mine was more a technical question: I'd like to know whether there are still around super-fast lenses (f<=1.0), which can be be used somehow on a modern DSLR. So not looking for buying tips.

Comment: If this is just an experiment, you might try a Fresnel lens, which can be *extremely* fast, with light-gathering better than f1.0. The downside is that images are of poor quality, AFAIK. Just mount one on an extension tube.

Comment: Thank you. Can you provide some links? While searching on google with "Fresnel lens" I get mostly links to the new 300mm with the Fresnel feature.

Comment: http://www.naturfotograf.com/need_speed00.html (not about the fresnel lens... other fast lenses). Page navigation is in the lower corner. Other old bits of the site completely unrelated that he's more than dabbled in: [uv photographs of flowers](http://www.naturfotograf.com/UV_flowers_list.html#top) and [other UV and IR](http://www.naturfotograf.com/UV_IR_rev00.html#top_page) things.  But glance at that 'need for speed' bit.